# Greasemonkey: Remove event handler added by plugin

Tags: jquery, event-handling, greasemonkey

I'm trying to remove a keydown event handler added by a "scroller" plugin into a page.

The page is this:
http://www.nacion.com/2012-05-15/Mundo/nobel-de-economia-cree-posible-pronta-desaparicion-de-zona-euro-.aspx

Basically I want that when I use the down/up arrows on my keyboard the page goes down instead of the small box where the plugin is applied.
I tried getting an instance of the plugin but for some reason it is not available once the page is loaded.

Another approach would be to force the greasemonkey script to be loaded before the script from the page is loaded (so I can remove it using greasemonkey) but I don't know if that is even possible.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page seems to use a custom or buggy implementation of [jQueryTOOLS Scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html).

The lousy UI experience is triggered by this code in the main page:

```
<script>
    // initialize scrollable para ademas
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.scroller_ademas").scrollable({
            size: 1,
            items: '#ademasaldea',
            vertical: true
        }).mousewheel({
            items: '#ademasaldea'
        });
    });
</script>
```

And all the `unbind()` calls and `keyboard = false` sets that should work, don't affect the keyboard hijack!

Fortunately, the offending `<script>` is fairly atomic, so Greasemonkey can block that offending JS without affecting anything else.

Block the JS by using [the stunningly-brilliant `checkForBadJavascripts` utility](https://gist.github.com/2620135).

Like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Block scrollable that's run amuck.
// @namespace   _pc
// @include     http://www.nacion.com/*
// @run-at      document-start
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2620135/checkForBadJavascripts.js
// ==/UserScript==

checkForBadJavascripts ( [
    [false, /items\:\s+'\#ademasaldea'/, null]
] );
```

Note that this will also stop the "Ademas en El Mundo" box from being scrollable, but you can fix that by adding

```
window.addEventListener ("load", function () {
    GM_addStyle ('#ademasaldea { height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; }');
}, false);
```

to the script.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for that. I'm glad I wasn't too far off :P never would have found the checkForBadJavascripts on my own though.

Comment: Actually, I thanked before testing it, it's strange but it is not blocking the script. The behavior is maintained.

Comment: I tested the script myself and it works.  You are using Firefox and Greasemonkey, right?  What versions of each?  Do you have or require a login to see the problem?

Comment: My mistake there. I'm using Tampermonkey on Chrome. I guess that's it. And the behavior is kind of strange, I have other code in the same script (I just import jquery and then remove some content from the page), but when I add your code it executes the script sometimes (if I refresh the page, sometimes it executes the script and sometimes it doesn't)

Comment: Please state Tampermonkey (etc.) in the question, right up front.  Anyway, Tampermonkey and Chrome userscripts handle document-start differently than FF GM.  This approach *might* not be possible on Chrome, and I've no more time budgeted to gin-up a workaround. Good luck.

Comment: Also, Chrome does not yet support the `beforescriptexecute` event.  So this approach will definitely not port.  You'll have to analyze the page's JS in more depth to create a counter.